# What does it mean to take a "vee product" of measures?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading a paper by Choski and Nadkarni called "The Maximal Spectral Type of a Rank-One Transformation". In it, they have a collection of measures $\mu_n$ on a space $(X, \mathcal{B})$, and then say that
$$
\bigvee_{n=0}^\infty \mu_n
$$ is another measure satisfying certain properties. Asking around, I can't find out what this symbol means in this context. The only things I know about it are that (1) it should be another measure on the same space, and (2) all the $\mu_n$ should be absolutely continuous with respect to it. What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect it to be the least upper bound of the measures $\mu_n$ with respect to the partial ordering "absolutely continuous with respect to". If the measures $\mu_n$ are finite, then such a least upper bound can be produced by first multiplying each $\mu_n$ by a positive number small enough to make the measure of the whole space $<1/2^n$ and then adding up all these rescaled measures.  (If the $\mu_n$ are not finite measures, then I'll leave the construction to analysts.)

Comment: Ah, that fits perfectly within the context. Thank you so much, I'd never have figured that out.

Comment: Can't you just take the pointwise supremum of the measures? The resulting functions is countably additive by using the Radon-Nikodym theorem with respect to the measure given by you and the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't (yet) see that the pointwise supremum would be countably (or even finitely) additive.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It is not. Please excuse my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

From a category theory perspective, I would expect it to be the measure space consisting of the disjoint union of countably many copies of $(X,\mathcal B)$, with the measure restricted to the $n$th copy of $(X,\mathcal B)$ being $\mu_n$.  Since you want this to be on $(X,\mathcal B)$, maybe there is a mapping from countably many copies of $(X,\mathcal B)$ to $(X,\mathcal B)$ that preserves some important structure of the measure.  (E.g. I can see how to do this if $(X,\mathcal B)$ is $\mathbb R$ with the Lebesgue measurable sets.)